# Use RegexpTokenizer in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I'm trying to apply the RegexpTokenizer in a column of the dataframe.

dataframe:

```
    all_cols
0   who is your hero and why
1   what do you do to relax
2   can't stop to eat
4   how many hours of sleep do you get a night
5   describe the last time you were relax
```

Script:

```
import re
import nltk
import pandas as pd
from nltk import RegexpTokenizer

#tokenization of data and suppression of None (NA)
df['all_cols'].dropna(inplace=True)

tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer("[\w']+")
df['all_cols'] = df['all_cols'].apply(tokenizer)
```

Error:

> TypeError: 'RegexpTokenizer' object is not callable

But I don't understand. When I use the other nltk tokenization mode, word_tokenize, works perfectly ...

Answer (score 2):

Note that when calling `RegexpTokenizer`, you're simply creating an instance of the class with a set of parameters (calling its `__init__` method). 
In order to actually tokenize the dataframe column with the specified pattern you must call its [`RegexpTokenizer.tokenize`](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/regexp.html) method:

```
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer("[\w']+")
df['all_cols'] = df['all_cols'].map(tokenizer.tokenize)

       all_cols
0  [who, is, your, hero, and, why]
1   [what, do, you, do, to, relax]
...
```

Answer (score 1):

First for remove missing values is necessary use [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) with specify column name and then use `tokenizer.tokenize` method, because your solution not remove missing values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'all_cols':['who is your hero and why',
                               'what do you do to relax', 
                               "can't stop to eat", np.nan]})
print (df)
                   all_cols
0  who is your hero and why
1   what do you do to relax
2         can't stop to eat
3                       NaN
```

---

```
#solution remove missing values from Series, not rows from df
df['all_cols'].dropna(inplace=True)
print (df)
                   all_cols
0  who is your hero and why
1   what do you do to relax
2         can't stop to eat
3                       NaN
```

---

```
#solution correct remove rows by missing values
df.dropna(subset=['all_cols'], inplace=True)
print (df)
                   all_cols
0  who is your hero and why
1   what do you do to relax
2         can't stop to eat
```

---

```
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer("[\w']+")
df['all_cols'] = df['all_cols'].apply(tokenizer.tokenize)
print (df)
                          all_cols
0  [who, is, your, hero, and, why]
1   [what, do, you, do, to, relax]
2           [can't, stop, to, eat]
```